# Problemas ao enviar dados para o banco com ionic

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic

Eu fiz uma aplicação web, com AngularJS e PHP, aqui no meu computador, onde eu cadastrado usuários e emails no banco e funciona perfeitamente.

Estou tentando fazer o mesmo com ionic, porém quando eu tento inseris, cadastrar um usuário, a seguinte mensagem é exibida no console:

> http://localhost:8888/sistemas/sistemas_web/ionic/crudAngular/www/php/salvar.php 500 (Internal Server Error)......ionic.bundle.js:19341 POST

- Alguém sabe dizer o por quê dessa mensagem?
- O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Verifique os logs do servidor, porque o erro 500 acontece lá. Pode ser um erro de sintaxe no código, ou um problema com os valores que você está postando (ou deixando de postar).

Comment: Como acesso esses logs, @bfavaretto?
O servidor é local.

Comment: Depende do servidor. Mas é mais fácil você olhar a resposta da requisição, na aba "network" das ferramentas do Chrome. Lá deve ter uma mensagem de erro e o número da linha com problemas no seu PHP.

Comment: Beleza, vou dar uma olhada nisso.
@bfavaretto, você já desenvolveu algum app mobile em ionic?

Comment: Não, nunca desenvolvi com ionic.

Comment: Não aparece aviso nenhum na aba network...
Mas no console, eu clico na setinha preta no aviso da mensagem que postei e aparece um monte de coisas:

>
(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:19341
sendReq @ ionic.bundle.js:19160
status.$get.serverRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:18872
processQueue @ ionic.bundle.js:23394
(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:23410
parent.$get.Scope.$eval @ ionic.bundle.js:24673

Comment: Na aba network tem que aparecer a requisição HTTP assim que ela for feita. Clicando nela você pode ver a resposta. Isso que você mostrou agora é do lado do cliente, mas seu erro é no servidor.

Comment: Nada @bfavaretto... Não aparece requisição HTTP na aba network.

Dê uma olhada no meu código:
> https://github.com/GugaSevero/crudAngular-Ionic/tree/master/www

Comment: Você precisa conferir se (1) seu js está enviando json válido no corpo da requisição, e (2) se as 3 chaves/campos que você tenta usar no código estão disponíveis nesse json.

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu tenho uma aplicação web que faz a mesma coisa e funciona... Eu teria que fazer essa conferência no js e verificar se essas 3 chaves estão corretas?

Comment: Você tem que dar um jeito de checar o que está sendo recebido pelo php.

Comment: Pois é, com angular, ficou complicado de ver o que está chegando no php usando Postman.

Comment: O problema é que você não pode acessar http://localhost:8888 dentro de um app, vc tem que setar o endereço para IP da sua máquina, faça o IP da sua máquina apontar para o localhost, ou use um servidor remoto., para saber o IP (no osx/linux: ifconfig, no window: ipconfig), setar isso no .htdocs

Answer (score 0):

Você esta consultando uma api certo?
Erro 500 geralmente é erro de sintaxe. 
Recomendo usar o postman (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop), realizando um post na mesma url que esta tentando.

Tentar habilitar os erros do php ele pode te ajudar.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fala Brother,

Naturalmente o erro é no servidor, provavelmente vc está tentando pegar os dados utilizando o array `$_POST`, sinto em informar que isso não vai funcionar, mas não se preocupe existe algo moleza que você pode fazer,

antes do seu código, no servidor, coloque isso:

```
$myData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
```

$myData vai ter o array com os dados da sua requisição.

abraço e espero que tenha sido útil :-D

Comment: Amigo, não sou o autor do post mas fiquei intrigado com sua resposta. Qual seria o motivo de sobrescrever a superglobal $_POST?

Comment: Tem quase 4 anos que escrevi isso rs, A super global $_POST não deve ser reescrita. então a atribuição deve ser feita para outra variável ;)